# NSURLMutableRequest with POST method and PHP

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, http-post, nsurlrequest

---

So I fixed the question codes with the new code that works and also changed the Title of the question for other people to be assist by it.

My problem was that inside the application i'm using in `POST` method, but on the `PHP` side, I'm using in `GET` method. Just changed it to `POST` and it worked perfectly.

Enjoy.

---

I keep getting error from my server that the username is wrong, what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks for your help.

```
- (void)addNewUser:(NSString *)username andDate:(NSDate *)date
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

    NSString * urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.myurl.com/url/insert.php"];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
    NSString *strDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];

    NSString *paramDataString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@&date=%@",[username stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],
                                 [strDate stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [request setHTTPBody:[paramDataString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES]];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                               NSString *requestData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                           }];
}
```

On the server side I have this: (PHP)

```
<?php
   header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf8");

   $connection = mysql_connect("localhost","myusername","mypassword");
   if(!$connection)
   {
       die("database connection failed:" . mysql_error());       
   }

   $db = mysql_select_db("db_users",$connection);
   if(!db)
   {
       die("database connection failed:" . mysql_error());
   }

   mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'",$connection);
?>

<?php 
    $varGet1 = $_POST['username'];
    $varGet2 = $_POST['date'];

    if (!$varGet1) {
        $message = "no username";
    } else if (!$varGet2) {
        $message = "no date";
    } else {
        $query = "INSERT INTO `Users` (username, date, first) VALUES('{$varGet1}','{$varGet2}','0')";

        $query = mysql_query($query,$connection);

        if($query) {
            $message = "Added";
        } else {
            $message = "Error";
        }
    }

    echo($message);

    mysql_close($connection);
?>
```

Comment: One thing is that you `GET` on your php while `POST`ing from objective-c...

Comment: Also, print out what your PHP script is getting for username, or print_r($_GET), but I suspect that @Alladinian is correct.

Comment: Listen, I'm don't know that much PHP, this is my first time using PHP, so I have some issues, I think that a lot of people can use this question to get help with POST and PHP because I didn't find something normal that I can use. This is as simple as it gets. @Alladinian you are right, I've changed it to `POST` and it worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: @YossiTsafar You're welcome. I added it as an answer also. Feel free to accept it if you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is really wrong. You just `GET` from your php while `POST`ing from objective-c. Switch to `$_POST` and you'll be good to go.